# Is it bad design to pass a form as an argument to a class just to access some of its variables or methods?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I found that I can either pass 8 arguments to a class constructor or just pass the form variable instead.

However, since I am not using everything on the form it seems like it may be bad design?

Also, the objects I do access I would need to provide accessors for.

Does it violate the principles of OOP?

Comment: "Pull over to the side of the road and let me see your OOP license" - I don't think there's a Code of Hammurabi for OOP that's so universally accepted.  Dude, if it works, use it.  If it doesn't, change it.

Comment: We need more context.  Generally I don't like seeing a form passed around, but I guess it could depend on what you are doing.

Comment: @duffymo, that philosophy was a bad idea in the 60's and the same applies to OOP. He's not asking if it works or not... clearly he is looking for advice and **Good** design, not how to hack together spaghetti code!

Comment: those 8 arguments probably form some kind of entity, and form only happens to display that entity, thats why exctract class with those 8 fields (or mb more depends on your case) , and pass it around. I am thinking theres at least 95% this is true for your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends - if you're using the form as that specific type of form, and "logically" it makes sense that you're working with the form, then by all means, pass a reference to the form.

It's just like any other class - If I was going to be accessing elements of an "employee", I'd write:

```
void DoSomething(Employee employee) { ...
```

Instead of:

```
void DoSomething(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime hireDate...) { ...
```

The first is very clean and obvious.

However, if the data you're using is unrelated to the form, it'd be better to encapsulate it into its own class usable by both the form and your class.

> Also, the objects I do access I would need to provide accessors for.

If this is the case, I suspect that having a class encapsulating the data is likely a better design...  The form could expose a property or method that returns an instance of that class, and pass it into your second class.

Comment: How many forms do you have that contain data that is unrelated to the form?  I'm a little concerned that someone will read this and take it as a licence to pass AddCustomerForm to their SaveCustomerMethod.  Would you condone that?

Comment: @Justin: No - I, personally, keep my forms entirely separate from the domain specific data...  I do agree with your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a gui form to either other gui components or even worse, a model/library that does work does break encapsulation and creates a tight coupling.

The form should abstract the data and the model below.  Other model or library classes should be passed model objects.  A typical pattern is to "bind" the gui layer to the model.

Instead of passing 8 variables, do the 8 variables logically break into different objects?  Ideally, you would pass an object or set of objects which may collectively contain 8 member variables.  Then you can simply pass references to objects that are contained in the same model that your gui is abstracting and bound to.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the class, I can almost guarantee the class taking 8 arguments is violating the Single Responsibility Principle.  It could be a class generated to represent a table in a database (or something to that effect) in which case you should encapsulate it in its own class as pass it around instead of the form.

Something else to consider is that the form you're reviewing is also violating SRP since it's both displaying data *and* being used as backing for another form.

Answer (score 1):

It *typically* is, because *typically* people are lazy or don't understand how to use events, so they write code like this:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    // stuff
}

class ChildForm : Form
{
    private MainForm _mainFrm;
    public ChildForm( MainForm frm )
    {
        _mainFrm = frm;
    }

    private void someButton_Click( ... )
    {
        _mainFrm.UpdateSomeText();
    }
}
```

That code creates a terrible coupling between two different UI classes.  Now, in a simple, internal, maybe throwaway project it is probably fine and you can write it once and move on.  In general it means that you very well may need to change your `ChildForm` class in response to changes in your `MainForm` class, which is undesirable and can be avoided via weak coupling mechanisms like events.

On the other hand, there are valid cases to pass in a form to a method or constructor, though these situations are less common in practice.  It all boils down to what you code is doing and if it is optimally designed.  There is no rulebook for this, it takes years of practice and requires that you make many mistakes first so that you know what to avoid before writing any code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a class that controls the formatting of a form (font, size, color etc) that could take a variable of type Form as an argument.  I could argue that THAT structure wouldn't violate OO principles.  Anything short of that probably not.

Even if you need customer details in the new class and you're tempted to pass the CustomerForm, which contains all the details you need, DON'T DO IT.  Create a customer class, provide an instance of that class from the form and pass that instance to the new class instead.  If you ever change the UI, or if you ever need to automate part of the workflow that used to be manual you'll be glad you did.